# Is there a different term for the "left-regular representation" of categories?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

After I thought of it, I saw the Yoneda lemma, which initially seemed to be the same thing,

but a more careful examination convinced me that the Yoneda lemma is significantly different.

Let morphismsto and morphismsfrom be given by

morphismsto($A$,$\mathcal{C}\hspace{.03 in}$) is the class of all morphisms to $A$ in $\mathcal{C}$

and
morphismsfrom($A$,$\mathcal{C}\hspace{.03 in}$) is the class of all morphisms from $A$ in $\mathcal{C}$

for categories $\mathcal{C}$ and objects A of $\mathcal{C}$.

For any category $\mathcal{C}$, one can form the "class-category" $\operatorname{L}\hspace{-0.03 in}\operatorname{R}(\mathcal{C}\hspace{.02 in})$ whose objects are

$\{\hspace{-0.03 in}$morphismsto($A$,$\mathcal{C}\hspace{.03 in}) : A\in \mathcal{C}\} \:$ and whose morphisms from $\: \{\hspace{-0.03 in}$morphismsto($A$,$\mathcal{C}\hspace{.03 in}) : A\in \mathcal{C}\} \:$ to

$\{\hspace{-0.03 in}$morphismsto($B$,$\mathcal{C}\hspace{.03 in}) : B\in \mathcal{C}\} \:$ are the class-functions $\;\;\; g \: \mapsto \: f\hspace{-0.05 in}\circ \hspace{-0.04 in}g \;\;\;$ for morphisms $\hspace{.04 in}f$ from $A$ to $B$.

Unless I'm missing something here, one can then define a faithful functor $\mathcal{F}\hspace{.02 in}$ from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\operatorname{L}\hspace{-0.03 in}\operatorname{R}(\mathcal{C}\hspace{.02 in})$

by $\;\;\; \mathcal{F}\hspace{.02 in}(A) \: = \: \{\hspace{-0.03 in}$morphismsto($A$,$\mathcal{C}\hspace{.03 in}) : A\in \mathcal{C}\} \;\;\;$ and $\;\;\; (\mathcal{F}\hspace{.02 in}(\hspace{.05 in}f : A\to B))(\hspace{.02 in}g) \: = \: f\hspace{-0.05 in}\circ \hspace{-0.04 in}g \;\;\;$, $\;\;\;$ and that

$\mathcal{F}\hspace{.02 in}$ is such that for all morphisms $\hspace{.04 in}f\hspace{-0.03 in}$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $\hspace{.04 in}f$ is a monomorphism if and only if $\hspace{.02 in}\mathcal{F}\hspace{.02 in}(\hspace{.05 in}f\hspace{.03 in})$ is injective.

By analogy with [groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_representation) and [rings and algebras](https://drexel28.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/representation-theory-left-regular-representation), I was imagining that construction would

be called the left-regular representation. $\:$ However, searching with google does not

turn up any use of the phrase "left-regular" in any context like what I'm talking about.

> I am well aware that $\operatorname{L}\hspace{-0.03 in}\operatorname{R}(\mathcal{C}\hspace{.02 in})$ can have objects and morphisms which are proper classes
>   
>   even if $\mathcal{C}$ is [locally small](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)#Small_and_large_categories). $\:$ Are there any *other* problems with my (attempted?) construction?
>   
>   Does my (attempted?) construction have a name?

If my construction works, then in cases where the classes morphismsto($A$,$\mathcal{C}\hspace{.03 in}$) are not necessarily sets but the classes morphismsfrom($A$,$\mathcal{C}\hspace{.03 in}$) *are* necessarily sets, one can get set objects by applying the construction to the opposite category and then using [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/23379/5810), although I haven't worked out whether or not that would also give the "monomorphism if and only if $\hspace{.02 in}\mathcal{F}\hspace{.02 in}(\hspace{.05 in}f\hspace{.03 in})$ is injective" property.

Comment: Maybe I'm tired, but your question is very hard to read. $LR(\mathcal{C})$ is probably either the [arrow category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category#Arrow_category) of $\mathcal{C}$, or the [slice category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category#Slice_category) (resp. coslice category) of objects over $A$ (resp. under $A$), both of which are example of comma categories. But I can't be sure because I'm not able to parse your question. Can you rephrase it without the new terminology ("to-$A$", "from-$A$")? What are the objects of $LR(\mathcal{C})$ exactly? The morphisms...?

Comment: [cont.] Is $A$ fixed? Variable? And I'm 95% sure that what you call the "left regular representation" is simply the Yoneda embedding. But again, I think it would really help if you wrote all this is plain words. Typically size issues are not really a problem when you're considering concrete applications, though some people have worked (and are still working) on making all this actually well-founded.

Comment: I figured out a way to avoid the new terminology, although it's far from clear that that helps. $\:$ (I could alternatively have replaced the $\operatorname{Range}$ operators with unions.) $\:$ The descriptions I've seen of the Yoneda embedding refer to local smallness, which is irrelevant for what I described. $\:$ (Unless I messed up, the construction of a concrete class-category works for _all_ categories, and local smallness is not a sufficient condition for the construction I described to produce a non-class category.) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I also find this question hard to read. In particular, I don't understand what you mean by $\text{Range}$. I also don't know what you think this buys you that the Yoneda embedding doesn't.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : $\;\;\;$ The $\operatorname{Range}$ of a map f is just the set of elements y of the codomain such that there exists an element x of the domain such that f(x)=y. $\:$ (I was under the impression that that was completely standard.) $\:$ It seems to me that the Yoneda embedding essentially _needs_ to discuss the Hom functor, whereas my description only used that to avoid the new terminology I originally posted. $\:$ I guess they might nonetheless turn out to be canonically isomorphic. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan $\;$ For one thing, it allows a hilariously easy way to express element-chasing arguments in purely category-theoretic language: replace each instance of "element of" with "morphism to", and replace each instance of function evaluation with composition. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @Ricky: what I'm confused about is the type of the input and output of $\text{Range}$. What I think I've got so far is that $\text{Range}$ here takes as input a function from $\text{Ob}(C)$ to $\text{Ob}(\text{Set})$, and hence returns as output a set of sets. Is that right? If so, I don't understand in what sense you want these ranges to be the objects of a category. In particular, what happens if $A$ and $B$ are two different (or maybe even nonisomorphic) objects where the corresponding ranges are the same sets of sets?

Comment: @Ricky: people already do that using the Yoneda embedding. (And this approach to element-chasing doesn't do everything you'd want it to: for example, the Yoneda embedding does not preserve epimorphisms.)

Comment: Yes, what I wrote was not the right thing. $\:$ I should've been taking a union, but that would make things more complicated, so I switched back to a verbal description and new terminology. $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freyd and Scedrov call this construction (seen as a functor $\mathcal{C} \to \text{Set}$ as in Qiaochu Yuan's answer) the **Cayley representation** in their book *Categories, Allegories*. They use it to prove the completeness theorem:

> Every universally quantified elementary sentence in the predicates of category theory true for the category of sets is true for all categories.

This construction first appeared in the Appendix of the Eilenberg-MacLane paper *General theory of natural equivalences*, where it is noted that it is an analogue of the left regular representation.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so here's a version of this construction that makes sense to me. Let $C$ be a small category. There is a functor $C \to \text{Set}$ which takes an object $c \in C$ to the disjoint union $\coprod_{d \in C} \text{Hom}(d, c)$ and which takes a morphism $f : c \to c'$ to the induced morphism

$$\coprod_{d \in C} \text{Hom}(d, c) \to \coprod_{d \in C} \text{Hom}(d, c').$$

This is the composition of the Yoneda embedding $C \to [C^{op}, \text{Set}]$ with the coproduct functor $[C^{op}, \text{Set}] \to \text{Set}$. The Yoneda lemma implies that it's faithful, from which it follows that every small category is [concretizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category).

I don't know a name for this functor. One way in which it's worse than the Yoneda embedding is that it's not full.

Comment: Does the Yoneda embedding yield a "class-category" (version of a category in which objects can be proper classes and morphisms can be class-functions) even when $C$ is not locally small? $\;$

Comment: @Ricky: the objects of a category aren't either sets or proper classes in the first place: they're just themselves members of a class. If $C$ isn't locally small then the Yoneda embedding doesn't take values in $[C^{op}, \text{Set}]$ but maybe it takes values in something bigger; you can make sense of statements like this using the machinery of Grothendieck universes.

Comment: Grothendieck universes require an increase in consistency strength, so it's not clear to me that "small" results proved using Yoneda embedding on not-locally-small categories can also be shown in ZFC (or even Morse-Kelly + Limitation of Size), whereas the alternative transformation can be interpreted in [NBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann–Bernays–Gödel_set_theory), and thus "small" results proved that way can also be proven in ZFC. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: If you want to do anything serious with not-locally-small categories you should not be working in NBG anyway.